# Stop PHP Storm indenting when I hit return?

Tags: phpstorm

When I press return in PHP Storm the new line is indented, even if the next line is not nested.

How can I stop the editor from doing this?

```
var something = 'visible';
  //After hitting return I'm indented 2 spaces
```

Comment: Its addition additional indentation. By not nested I mean for example the code above where there is no reason to indent the next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From PHPStorm 7.1 on you should find the option here:

**Settings**->**Code Style**->**General**

Try disabling "Formatter control"

[image]

You can also read from their [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/reformatting-source-code.html) about the use of tags to turn feature on and off again directly from your code, only when needed:

```
//@formatter:on
```

or

```
//@formatter:off
```

If this is not what you are looking for then your problem may be related to indent style, there is a known issue about that [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-6328), I summarize it in generally checking and changing configuration in Settings|Code Style|Wrapping and Braces, choose PHP tab, click to "Predefined..."

To wrap it up there is also a very useful video from Laracasts (Laravel video tutorials), "How to be awesome in PHPStorm" that was helpful for me, here is the [link](https://laracasts.com/series/how-to-be-awesome-in-phpstorm/episodes/8).

Comment: I already have that option unchecked (so different from your screenshot).

Comment: Answer updated according to your comment